# Facebook Login WebView display not show my Facebook App logo

Tags: android, facebook, webview, android-webview, facebook-login

I have already followed the instructions on [Android - Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/) and the login process is working. The problem now is that the Facebook login webview is not showing my app logo which I created on Facebook Developer App Settings.

Here are some pictures:

[image: My App Facebook Login compare to LINE Facebook Login]

My question is, how do I make my Facebook login look like the LINE app Facebook Login webview?.